# Creating table in joomla web installer taking long time

Tags: database, joomla, wamp, joomla2.5

While creating tables in Joomla web installer taking long time in Wampserver, after 2 hours also it is not moving forward. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the php error log you will probably find that PHP has timed out.

Edit the php.ini file and change this parameter to :-

```
max_execution_time = 240
```

When you have completed the install change it back to no more than 60.